# Redirect works but render fails on the same path for my comment system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello guys~ I'm kind of new to rails here. And I have a controler like this in my create action, but my failed creation for a comment always direct to "Template Missing". I wonder how to solve that since my success is working alright with the same path ... thank you very much~

```
def create
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  @comment = @book.comments.build(params[:comment]) if signed_in?
  @comment.user = current_user

  if @comment.save
    flash[:success] = "Comment posted"
    redirect_to book_path(@book)
  else
    render book_path(@book)
  end
end
```

Routes

```
resources :books do
  resources :comments, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `render :show`.

`render` does not accept a URL like this. It accepts the name of the template that you are rendering, among other things. Check out the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render) for more examples of what you can pass to `render`.